ASP.NET : access API's using Oauth Github provider
How can I use this access token, 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, along with the scope user:email and token type bearer, generated by the GitHub OAuth endpoint (https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token), to authorize access or not to my ASP.NET APIs?
For front-end, I use Angular.
This code is in my program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOAuth("Github", "Git Hub", gitHubOptions =>
            {
                gitHubOptions.ClientId = "client_id";
                gitHubOptions.ClientSecret = "secret_client";
                gitHubOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Logincode");
                gitHubOptions.AuthorizationEndpoint = "http://github.com/login/oauth/authorize";
                gitHubOptions.TokenEndpoint = "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token";
                gitHubOptions.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.github.com/user";
                gitHubOptions.Scope.Add("user:email");
                // Retrieving user information is unique to each provider.
                gitHubOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
                gitHubOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "login");
                gitHubOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:name", "name");
                gitHubOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email",  ClaimValueTypes.Email);
                gitHubOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:github:url", "url");
            });

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
